# How to get Hibernate Envers with Spring integration testing?

Tags: spring, hibernate, hibernate-envers

**Is there some way to get Hibernate Envers to run *immediately* on the call to save or update instead of going at the end of the transaction ?**

I have a `@Transactional` annotation on my (effectively end-to-end test). Since the code doesn't contain test methods I'm unable to put "flush" or whatever in it, (short of editing non-test code, which is not the desire).

**I'm not sure how to get Envers log working on the calls. I need it to work  as I'm using the Envers audit tables to check old entries at runtime, and would like to create test cases for this functionality.**

I have the following code for unit testing :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration("/src/webapp")
@EnableWebMvc
@Transactional
@TestPropertySource(locations= {"classpath:/config/common.properties"}, properties = {"..."})
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"..."})
public class Test {
    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService detailsService;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac)
            .build();
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Are you using a spring-boot application ? Can you add your code as it will be helpful to get your solution ?

Comment: Ok. I'm seeing that